# Open up for remote website request on IIS 8

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, iis, iis-8

I have a IIS 8 on a windows server 8 that currently has its firewall shutdown. I am trying to open up for other computers to access the website that this IIS is running. I can access it locally. I can ping the server remotely but when I try to access the website on the server I get a "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".

I have seen articles on the internet for a "enable remote connections" but have failed to find that setting.

What am I missing?

Here are my current site bindings:
[image]

Comment: Can you a screenshot of the bindings you've used? You need to make sure you've bound the Website to listen on your external IP address.

Comment: Added site bindings to Original post